# Highcharts using value not an array Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, highcharts

I am trying to use the Highcharts with ajax.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: 'my/rest/get_devices_usage.php', 
        type: 'POST',
        data: {},
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
           series = [];

            var months = [];
            var device_names = [];
            var usages = [];


            for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) 
            {   
                months.push(data[i].month); 
                device_names.push(data[i].device_name);
                usages.push(parseFloat(data[i].usage_sum));
            }

            var data = [];
            data = generateData(months, device_names, usages);


 //create graph
        $('#panel-body').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: ''
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

            xAxis: {
            categories: months
            },

            series: data
        });



  function generateData(cats, names, points) {
        var ret = {},
            ps = [],
            series = [],
            len = cats.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ps[i] = {
                x: cats[i],
                y: points[i],
                n: names[i]
            };
        }
      //populate the graph
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var p = ps[i];
                series.push({
                name: p.n,
                data: [p.y]
                });
            }
        return series;
    }


     },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {

        }     
      });
```

[image]

I need to show on the chart the value, name of device and month/year. The problem is, that when I try to use the series data only as array that has only one value, then I can see only one category (even if I have 5 categories). How can I solve it?

Can I somehow make to see all categories that I have, and just put my result to the right category?

Comment: If you have 5 categories, you need to supply a datapoint *for all five.*  If you're omitting the data (only 1 value in the array) then you need to supply *empty data* for those other categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it a little bit different. Solution for my problem is kind of as Draco18s says...How I solved it is, that I have specified on which position I want to see my value of series.

So I have made as first indexof my item in a list. and then I used this index in series data. So solution looks like this

```
            $.ajax({
            url: 'my/rest/get_devices_usage.php', 
            type: 'POST',
            data: {},
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
               series = [];

                var months = [];
                var device_names = [];
                var usages = [];

                for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) 
                {   
                    months.push(data[i].month); 
                    device_names.push(data[i].device_name);
                    usages.push(parseFloat(data[i].usage_sum));
                }

                var data = [];
                data = generateData(months, device_names, usages);


            $('#panel-body').highcharts({
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                chart: {
                    title: '',
                    type: 'column'
                },

                xAxis: {
                categories: months
                },

                series: data
            });



      function generateData(cats, names, points) {
            var ret = {},
                ps = [],
                series = [],
                len = cats.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                ps[i] = {
                    x: cats[i],
                    y: points[i],
                    n: names[i]
                };
            }
          //populate the graph
            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

                var p = ps[i];
///Solution
                var month = 0;
               //find position of the actual month
                month = months.indexOf(p.x);

                    series.push({
                    name: p.n,
                    data: [[month, p.y]]
                    });
                }
///Solution
            return series;
        }


     },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {

        }     
      });
```

So just count on which category is your value, and put it on that category
data:[[category_position, value]] ...that's it :)

Thank you guys for help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set [`max`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.max) for xAxis to, in this case, 4 (because 5 categories in an array indexed from 0).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pa2pssc6/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        xAxis: {
        categories: ['a','b','c','d','e'],
        max: 4
      },
        series: [{
            data: [1]
        }]
    });
});
```